# Show values from other tables in a loop

Tags: php, mysql, css, database, loops

In my database I have 3 tables:

**train_information:**

```
+----------+-----------------+------------------+
| train_id | number_of_axles | number_of_bogies |
+----------+-----------------+------------------+
|        1 |               4 |                2 |
+----------+-----------------+------------------+
```

**axle:**

```
+---------+----------+------+----------+
| axle_id | train_id | axle | distance |
+---------+----------+------+----------+
|       1 |        1 |    1 |     2500 |
|       2 |        1 |    2 |     5000 |
|       3 |        1 |    3 |     2500 |
+---------+----------+------+----------+
```

**bogie:**

```
+----------+----------+---------+----------+
| bogie_id | train_id | axle_nr | bogie_nr |
+----------+----------+---------+----------+
|        1 |        1 |       1 |        1 |
|        2 |        1 |       2 |        1 |
|        3 |        1 |       3 |        2 |
|        4 |        1 |       4 |        2 |
+----------+----------+---------+----------+
```

When something gets inserted in the `train_information` table, a trigger also inserts in the other 2 tables (Distance & bogie_nr get updated later, but in this example everything is filled in already).

Now I make a train model based on the `distance & axle` values.
Right now it looks like this:

```php
<div id="axles">
    <!--This is the last (useless) axle, which always is 0-->
    <div id="useless_circle"></div>
    <!--Here we create the axles and style them with the distances-->
    <?php
        $show_axle = $database->axles($_GET['train_id']);
        $total_distance = 0;
        foreach($show_axle as $number_ofaxles){
            $total_distance += $number_ofaxles['distance']; ?>
            <div id="axle" name="test" style="margin-left:<?= $total_distance/25000*100;?>%">
                <?= "<div id='circle'>" . $number_ofaxles['axle'] . "</div>";?>
            </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

And:

```php
function axles($id){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM axle WHERE train_id = :id2";
    $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $sth->bindParam(":id2", $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->execute();
    return $sth->fetchAll();
}
```

Now, the page looks like this (With the values of the DB):

[image: How the page looks.]

*The code I provided is only for the axles! (the 4 circles beneath the train)!*

Now, what I want:

Right now, I just ask for the value of the axle table. but it only contains 3 axles instead of 4. This is because I want to know the distance BETWEEN each axle. so I always need 1 less.
I solved this by making 1 extra div that creates the circle (axle) and places is to the left.

What I would like to have is something like:
show the `axle_nr` from the `bogie` table (So it shows 4).
Get the `distance` where `axle` = `axle_nr`.
Then you always keep 1 empty. because axle 4. does not exist in the `axle` table.
So i want to make a check: if axle does not exist then distance = 0. I don't want to insert this in the database, but just so i don't need the useless axle div anymore AND the axle stays on the left.

Why do I want this?
This way I can check which bogie numbers are the same, so I can give them each another color etc. Also I won't need the useless_axle div!

**EDIT:**

*Simple explanation:*

I want to show the `Axle_nr` from the `bogie` table. (So it displays 4 circles)
However! i will need the `Distance` from the `axle` table in order to make a train figure.
as you can see the `axle` table has 1 less axle than the `bogie` table.
So i want the "Not existing" axle to have a value of 0. I want it 0 because then it will show up on the beginning of the train. (Just like the useless axle right now)

**CODE EDIT:**

Right now I have got this:

```php
   <div id="axles">
        <?php 
        $testingggg = $database->axleees();
        foreach ($testingggg as $lol){  ?>
            <div id="axle">
                    <div id="circle" name="<?= $lol['axle'] ?>"><?= $lol['axle'] ?></div>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
```

And:

```php
function axleees() {
        $sql = "SELECT ti.axle_nr, ti.train_id, ti.bogie_nr, uti.axle_id, uti.train_id, uti.axle, uti.distance
                FROM bogie as ti
                JOIN axle as uti
                ON ti.train_id = uti.train_id
                WHERE ti.train_id = :train_id";
        $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $sth->bindParam(":train_id", $_GET["train_id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sth->execute();
        return $sth->fetchAll();
    }
```

And it shows me 12 axles instead of 4!

***EDIT:***

it is showing me 4 axles now which is correct.
However I also need the correct distances. Code I have:

```
    <div id="axles">
    <?php
        $total_distance = 0;
        foreach ($testingggg as $lol){ 
            $total_distance += $lol['distance'];
    ?>
            <div id="axle" style="margin-left:<?= $total_distance/25000*100;?>%">
                    <div id="circle" name="<?= $lol['axle'] ?>"><?= $lol['axle_nr'] ?></div>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
```

Right now, it shows me that every axle has a margin of 10%. this is correct (if you only have the first axle). it needs to be something like 10-15-10-15 or so. How do I do this?

**EDIT:**

Right now I have the following query:

```
function axleees() {
        $sql = "SELECT ti.axle_nr, ti.train_id, ti.bogie_nr, uti.axle_id, uti.train_id, uti.axle, uti.distance
                    FROM bogie as ti
                    JOIN axle as uti
                    ON ti.train_id = uti.train_id
                    WHERE ti.train_id = :train_id
                    GROUP BY uti.axle_id";
        $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $sth->bindParam(":train_id", $_GET["train_id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sth->execute();
        return $sth->fetchAll();
    }
```

And I call it here:

```
<div id="axles">
            <?php
                $total_distance = 0;
                foreach ($testingggg as $lol){ 
                $total_distance += $lol['distance'];
                $margin = $total_distance/25000*100;
            ?>
            <div id="axle" style="margin-left:<?= $margin; ?>%">
                    <div id="circle" name="<?= $lol['axle'] ?>"><?= $lol['axle_nr'] ?></div>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
            </div>
```

**Image EDIT:**

[image: train example]

Comment: I still didn't got your question. I would suggest explain it simple. So, people can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that this is a rather convoluted way to work around the original problem.  You are shy one axle, and need that axle to be in your database.  You said that all values are added via a trigger in the database.  If that is the case, why not add a value that has a distance of '0' with the id of the train.  This will give you not only the axle, but the rendered div as well.

If your table looked like this after generation (please forgive me if the index is off in the wrong direction.  I am struggling just a touch to understand your database layout):

```
+---------+----------+------+----------+
| axle_id | train_id | axle | distance |
+---------+----------+------+----------+
|       0 |        1 |    0 |        0 |
|       1 |        1 |    1 |     2500 |
|       2 |        1 |    2 |     5000 |
|       3 |        1 |    3 |     2500 |
+---------+----------+------+----------+
```

Then the following whould generate all circles, including the one that has a margin (or distance as you stated earlier) of '0'.  Technically speaking, you have an axle with a distance of '0' from the front of the train, so why not track it in your database.

```
<div id="axles">
    <!--Here we create the axles and style them with the distances-->
    <?php
    $show_axle = $database->axles($_GET['train_id']);
    $total_distance = 0;
    foreach($show_axle as $number_ofaxles){
        // Because the first value is 0, the first run will be against the left edge.
        $total_distance += $number_ofaxles['distance']; ?>
        <div id="axle" name="test" style="margin-left:<?=$total_distance/25000*100;?>%">
            <?= "<div id='circle'>" . $number_ofaxles['axle'] . "</div>";?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Taking this approach both simplifies and solves your problem.

Comment: yeah, although the PO states he DOESN'T want to store the axle in the DB, I also think your answer is the way to proceed. If the train has 4 axles, put 4 rows there and simplify the calculations! XD

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
   $sql = "SELECT ti.axle_nr, ti.train_id, ti.bogie_nr, uti.axle_id, uti.train_id, uti.axle, uti.distance
            FROM bogie as ti
            JOIN axle as uti
            ON ti.train_id = uti.train_id
            WHERE ti.train_id = :train_id";
```

to

```
$sql = "SELECT ti.axle_nr, ti.train_id, ti.bogie_nr, uti.axle_id, uti.train_id, uti.axle, uti.distance
                    FROM bogie as ti
                    LEFT JOIN axle as uti
                    ON ti.train_id = uti.train_id AND uti.axle_id = ti.axle_nr
                    WHERE ti.train_id = :train_id";
```

Or run for testing next sql:

```
SELECT
      b.*,
      a.*
 FROM bogie AS b
 LEFT JOIN axle AS a ON a.train_id = b.train_id AND a.axle_id = b.axle_nr
WHERE b.train_id = 1
```

return 4 rows instead of 12.

Comment: This helped me, tough got 1 little problem with it haha Check edit @Danila Ganchar

Comment: I actually don't want to add 5. as you can see i have distances in my axle table. I make a sum from those. so 2500/25000*100 = 10. so the first axle has a margin-left of 10%. and i need to do that with the rest aswell. Problem for now is: it only does that for the first axle. so result is 10%, 10%, 10%, 10%. while it actually should be 10%, 20%, 10% Since i only have 3 axles there.

Comment: I think I understood what you want.Change in sql 'GROUP BY b.bogie_id' to 'GROUP BY a.axle_id'. Distances will be: 2500/25000*100 = 10, 5000/25000*100 = 20, 2500/25000*100 = 10. Is it right?

Comment: It is working with that @Danila Ganchar, The axles (Circles) Get positioned correctly. though i'm missing 1 axle. (becuase it only has 3 axles in the axle table). What i want is: see 4 axles, where 3 axles have a distance and 1 has not. (it is 0) so it stays at the left.

Comment: Exist 2 ways. First: add column 'axle_id' to bogie table(or bogie_id to axle table) for relation. Second: solve the problem with 2 sql queries. I really not understand what you want))) In your example you working only with distance. Why you can't use just: 'SELECT * FROM axle'???

Comment: Made an edit. Also i want the row: axle and axle_nr to be connected. instead of making new rows.

Comment: @Mitch last version in answer.

Comment: It is showing me 4 axles :) But they all have a margin of 0%. @Danila Ganchar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79503/discussion-between-danila-ganchar-and-mitch).